# Question concerning the meaning of an equality sign in a commutative diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$ 
I have the following question:

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category, $X,Y,Z\in Ob(\mathscr{C}),
\ f\in Mor(X,Y),\ g\in Mor(Y,Z)$ and $h\in Mor(X,Z)$.

> Question: What does the equality sign in the following diagram mean?

$$
\begin{CD}
  X @>f>> Y\\
  @| @VVgV \\
  X @>>h> Z  
\end{CD}
$$

Does the equality sign only emphasize that the two objects are indeed the same, or does it mean that we have $X\stackrel{id}{\rightarrow}X$ or does it mean that we have an arbitrary isomorphism $X\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}X$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The equal sign indeed stands for $\mathrm{id}_X$. Most of the time, it is because either it makes the diagram embeddable in the plane (avoid arrow crossing) or the author did not have the skills/tools to make a triangle diagram (I heard about a time when `tikz-cd` did not exist...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It represents the identity map. The notation also implies that you could think of the diagram as being the same as a triangle, with the two $X$s being squished together (kind of like a quotient of the diagram or something).